# withRouter vs react-router-dom hooks (useHistory, useLocation, useMatch)

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Sometimes I use withRouter to wrap my component and use `history`, `location` from `props`, sometimes I use `useHistory()`, `useLocation()`.
I don't know the advantages or disadvantages of these two ways to use.

Comment: `withRouter` is a HOC, whereas the "use" ones are hooks. HOCs can wrap any React component, hooks can only be used in functional ones. `withRouter` passes in ALL the router props, hooks let you access specific ones only. They don't have objective advantages or disadvantages, they're 2 different things

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're asking is not specific to `react-router-dom`, you're asking about the differences between using `HOC pattern vs using hooks` in React which is in a nutshell a decision between these values in projects:

- Readability
- Reusability
- Customisation and usage
- Debugging
- Testability
- Performance

which you can know more about them in these links:

https://medium.com/simply/comparison-hocs-vs-render-props-vs-hooks-55f9ffcd5dc6

https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-higher-order-components

[https://medium.com/javascript-scene/do-react-hooks-replace-higher-order-components-hocs-7ae4a08b7b58#:~:text=For%20broadly%2Dused%20cross%2Dcutting,UI%20code%20in%20your%20app](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/do-react-hooks-replace-higher-order-components-hocs-7ae4a08b7b58#:%7E:text=For%20broadly%2Dused%20cross%2Dcutting,UI%20code%20in%20your%20app).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yeah I know that `withRouter` is a `HOC` and `useHistory` is a hook. Anyway, I want to understand more about them to decide when to use them.

Comment: I want to understand the difference in Performance.